# How to implement function that fires when JavaScript object is garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Actually, garbage collected, destroyed, or otherwise blown out of scope. What I want to do is unbind event handlers on non-DOM elements when an object that has called the bind method is destroyed.

---

EDIT: I've looked at my code some more, and decided that the only place where I really need this is when the module that contains the object is no longer needed. This is typically when the user loads a new view (it's like "goes to a new page" but in AJAX, right?). So what I did was wrote a simple wrapper method around the bind method, which modifies the callback function to additionally unbind the handler on custom `viewchange` event. Then I ensure that the `viewchange` is actually triggered whenever the view is changed.

Comment: I suspect this to be impossible, but it's tantalizing.

Comment: how are you adding the event handlers?

Comment: Also, why exactly are you binding event handlers to non-DOM objects?

Comment: I suggest you give a practical example because this seems too strange to discuss in the abstract.

Comment: @Pointy, @entonio: I'm writing an all-AJAX event-driven application, so I use event extensively to handle all sorts of things. For example, I fire events to request data, and then the data module fires event when it's done. This allows me to avoid multiple levels of nested callbacks, and gives ability to have multiple modules handle data callback for requests initiated by one module. Another example would be a list of items that have ownership associated with them, which needs to be updated on the spot when user logs in. Login success event fires, and the responsible module updates the list.

Comment: @Anurag: I have a custom event system. It has objects for each event type, and the object keeps a map of event handlers and their string IDs. So I wanted to add a feature to auto-unbind handlers whose associated objects (handler owners) have died.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible.  There's no way of knowing when something has been or is going to be garbage collected.  It's best to ensure you `unbind` any events before allowing an object to be destroyed.

Comment: Yeah, I did some reading meanwhile, and came to the same conclusion. Some languages provide a mechanism for doing some cleanup prior to destruction of an object either by garbage collector or something else, so I thought maybe JavaScript has this, too.

Answer (score 3):

## Use [`FinalizationRegistry`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry)

As of August 2020, modern browsers have support for the `FinalizationRegistry` method defined by the ECMAScript 2021 (**ES12**) language specification.

```
const registry = new FinalizationRegistry((value) => {
    console.log(value);
});
const obj = {};
registry.register(obj, "Object 'obj' is garbage collected");
```

Here we create an instance of `FinalizationRegistry` and attached an object to it using `.register`. Soon as this object is garbage collected, the callback function passed to the `FinalizationRegistry` method is run.

Comment: For @Jean-François_Fabre, I already flag the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11864044/11630806) for duplicate (less view, more recent and relative to android and not only to js)

Comment: As read in the documentation for callbacks, it looks like it's not very reliable https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry#notes_on_cleanup_callbacks